# Can diagonally dominant matrix be written as the sum of diagonally dominant matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I am trying to work out an property of Eigen-decomposition.

Assume that

- $A$ is symmetric and all-positive, i.e. $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$ and $A_{ij}>0$.
- $A$ is diagonally dominant, i.e. $A_{ii}\geq \sum_{j\neq i}A_{ij}$ for all $i$.

Suppose the Eigen-decomposition of $A$ looks like $$A = U\Lambda U^T=\sum_i \lambda_iu_iu_i^T,$$
where $u_i$ is the $i$-th column of orthogonal $U$ and $\Lambda=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$.

Can we prove or disprove that (all or some) $u_iu_i^T$ are also diagonally dominant?

-------------[edit]---------------

What if we assume in addition that

- $A$ is normalized by its row/column sums (doubly stochastic matrix), i.e. $\sum_i A_{ij}=\sum_j A_{ij}=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, counterexample
$$\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$$
Which disprove the rule.

Comment: What if we further assume the matrix to be normalized by both row and column?